# C# how to return data adapter to Class to Form

Tags: c#

I have a `C#` class which returns a data adapter then I need to collect it from **FORM** and loop the data within data adapter.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
returned_adapter.Fill(dt);

//Read values using iterator
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string column1 = row["column_name"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(dt);

            List<T> result = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var data= new Product()
                {
                    item1 = (string)row["item1"],
                    item2= (int)(decimal)row["item2"],
                    item3 = (string)row["item3"],
                    Pritem4ce = (decimal)(double)row["item4"]

                };

                result.Add(data);
            }
```